# What happens if i delete my forked repository?

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repository.Now if i delete that forked repository will it also delete the following merge history? And if i re-forked it again and make a pull request will the merge history reappear again? [Github merge history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2gcB.png)

ps: i want to delete and start again because of merge history "Merge 'gajabar:main' into main". I tried [this](https://ballistic-wish-492.notion.site/Write-up-on-fixing-Merge-branch-gajabaar-main-into-main-31c2b2899f8344cc885f00f236dcbf23?pvs=4) method to solve but the merge message appear again.